# Как удалить все виджеты со слоя (компоновщика) Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

У меня есть слой, который заполняется виджетами

```
clickbleLabel *noteNameLbl = new clickbleLabel[info->amountNotes];

for(int i = 0; i < info->amountNotes; i++)
{
    noteNameLbl[i].setText(info->notes[i].name);
    showNotesLay->addWidget(&noteNameLbl[i]);
}
```

слой showNotesLbl определен ранее

```
QGridLayout *showNotesLay = new QGridLayout;
```

clickbleLabet - наследний от QLabel, который посылает сигнал, когда на его нажимают

У меня есть функция:

```
void GUI::clianNoteSlot()
{
 while(QLayoutItem *tmpItem = showNotesLay->takeAt(0))
    {
        delete tmpItem->widget();
        delete tmpItem;
    }
}
```

которая должна удалять все виджеты, но при выполнении

```
delete tmpItem->widget();
```

программа аварийно завершается с сообщением:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть при выполнении

```
delete tmpItem->widget();
```

отладчик переходит в

```
clickbleLabel
```

Без понятия, как это исправить

Comment: вызывайте у виджетов `deleteLater()`

Answer (score 0):

Их также нужно удалять с самого слоя:

```
while(QLayoutItem *tmpItem = showNotesLay->itemAt(0)) {
    showNotesLay->removeItem(tmpItem);
    showNotesLay->removeWidget(tmpItem->widget());
    delete tmpItem->widget();
    delete tmpItem;
}
showNotesLay->update();
```